# Making the right side of an image cut out accordin to screen resolution

Tags: html, css, image

I have a header on my screen that contains 7 images.

I want the header to cover width: 100% site. The header is 1920*50px. I want the right side of the header to cut out if the screen resolution is less than 1920*1080 and not the left side.

Here's the header in html:

```
<div id="apDiv1">
    <img src="Bilder/navbar/images/navbar-rambech_01.jpg" width="53" height="50" />
    <a href="index.html"><img src="Bilder/navbar/images/navbar-rambech_02.jpg" width="236" height="50" alt="Rambech" /></a>
    <a href="sourcebans"><img src="Bilder/navbar/images/navbar-rambech_03.jpg" width="202" height="50" alt="Sourcebans" /></a>
    <a href="forum.php"><img src="Bilder/navbar/images/navbar-rambech_04.jpg" width="135" height="50" alt="Forum" /></a>
    <a href="admin.html"><img src="Bilder/navbar/images/navbar-rambech_05.jpg" width="199" height="50" alt="Søke Admin" /><img src="Bilder/navbar/images/navbar-rambech_06.jpg" width="116" height="50" alt="VIP" /></a>
    <img src="Bilder/navbar/images/navbar-rambech_07.jpg" width="979" height="50" max-width="100%" />
</div>
```

Comment: I think the following link will be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689745/resize-images-as-viewport-resizes-without-sides-being-cut-off

Comment: we will need your css code to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

Add the below code to your CSS. This will cut images on the right side.

```
#apDiv1 {
    width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```